# Magento URL Rewrite

Tags: magento, url, url-rewriting

I have no idea how to do URL rewrites so I'm hoping this is posible and someone could donate my a snip-it of code.

Here's what I would like:

I would like to write these category URLs ...

```
maybe-category-here/category-something-here.html?p=2
```

I would like to write the ends of the second, third, forth, etc pages where ".html?p=2

to something like:

maybe-category-here/category-something-here/page-2.html etc

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

im no big describer,, but here is to get direct help

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/what-url-rewrites-are-and-why-they-are-important

Comment: My URL Management has this, ID Path: category/6  Request Path: category.html then Target Path: catalog/category/view/id/6 How am I suppose to rewrite this to something like above?